# Informix drivers for. Net without sdk

Tags: .net, database, informix

I'm developing small app reading data from informix database
I couldn't find easy way to connect to that dB, apart of installing IBM sdk

This makes app deployment quite difficult (user have to install sdk and add registry entry), and can't be run by user with lower privileges level

I wonder i there is a way to use some other dlls /config files so app can work in portable mode without need installing 3rd party tools nor software

Maybe we. Can use jdbc drivers in. Net?

I'm using great free dB IDE - dB eavier and noticed it can quite easily download informix driver and use it without any additional steps / installations

Any help / tips will be highly appreciated!

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm not sure that Informix Connect — the runtime version of Informix ClientSDK — is a significant benefit here.  It probably requires registry entries etc too.

Comment: Where I can find this Connect library? Id survive with .reg in worst case. I just dont want user to install SDK. For other DBs it is usually enough to include DLLs in app package... Why Informix is so different ?